# Linking tables in MySQL to their respective data with Flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am trying to display a list of tables in flask (pulled from mysql database) that link to their respective data. I have been able to list the tables, though when I click on them I get an error: "%b requires a bytes-like object, or an object that implements **bytes**, not 'dict'"

Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, flash, jsonify
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL,MySQLdb
 
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'forddb'
app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'
mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cur.execute('SHOW TABLES')
    parts = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('index.html', parts=parts)

@app.route('/tableinfo')
def tableinfo():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cur.execute('SHOW TABLES')
    tables=cur.fetchall()
    for table in tables:
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM %s', (table))
        data = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('inspection.html', data=data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

my index.html is:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<h1>{% block title %} Pick Part Number to Start Inspection {% endblock %}</h1>
{% for parts in parts %}
    <a href="{{ url_for('tableinfo') }}">
        <h2>{{ parts.Tables_in_forddb }}</h2>
    </a>
    <hr>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

I am new to flask and programing in general and was hoping to understand how to loop through tables in SQL database, then assign them to href links of the same name, then route to that tables data. I am not even sure if this is the right approach, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

finally figured it out changed the 'tableinfo' route to:

```
@app.route('/tableinfo/<id>')
def tableinfo(id):
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('SHOW TABLES')
    tables=cur.fetchall()
    for table in tables:
        cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {id}")
        table = cur.fetchall()
        return render_template('inspection.html', table=table)
```

and index.html to:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<h1>{% block title %} Pick Part Number to Start Inspection {% endblock %}</h1>

    {% for tables in tables %}
        <hr>
        <a href="{{ url_for('tableinfo', id=tables.Tables_in_forddb) }}">
            <h2>{{ tables.Tables_in_forddb }}</h2>
        </a>
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: `cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {id}")` -> be aware that using string formatting like this can leave your application vulnerable to [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), for example if a malicious user set `id` as `'(select name, password from users) x; --'.  `. [Famous comic](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: @snakecharmerb I agree! Also OP you can go ahead and check out Flask-SQLAlchemy it allows you not only to use MySQL, SQLite, and other DB's using the Framework using that is recommended but not necessary. https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/